# C# How do I read Excel cell XML values with character level formatting? (Multiple <t> elements within <si>)

Tags: c#, xml, excel, deserialization, nsxmlelement

I am working on a small application that will read the contents of an excel worksheet and import all the data as strings into a windows form datagridview.

I have successfully implemented Dietmar Schoder's code example to do this. Special thanks to him for posting it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of?fid=1864959&df=10000&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=5149734

I am new to XML and have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

The cells with "character level" formatting contain two or more separate `<t>` text values within the `<si>` xml element.

Here is a snippet from the excel file's sharedstrings.xml file

```
<si>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <b/>
        <sz val="12"/>
        <color rgb="FFFF0000"/>
        <rFont val="Arial"/>
        <family val="2"/>
      </rPr>
      <t>Text A</t>
    </r>
    <r>
      <rPr>
        <b/>
        <sz val="12"/>
        <color theme="1"/>
        <rFont val="Arial"/>
        <family val="2"/>
      </rPr>
      <t xml:space="preserve"> Text B</t>
    </r>
  </si>
```

This cell contains the text "Text A Text B" but returns null because the cell has character level formatting and therefore two `<t>` tags. 
"Text A" has strike-through, colored differently or bold etc and "Text B" doesn't.

The text values are assigned with the following line of code.

```
Text = Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].t;
```

Is there anyway to concatenate the strings from both `<t>` elements before assigning it to the Text variable?

Edit: I think I have no narrowed the problem down to the sharedstrings.cs file and the deserialization of the sharedstrings.xml

```
SharedStrings = DeserializedZipEntry<sst>(GetZipArchiveEntry(zipArchive, @"xl/sharedStrings.xml"));
```

sst class:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")]
[XmlRoot("sst", Namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")]

public class sst
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string uniqueCount;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string count;

    [XmlElement("si")]
    public SharedString[] si;

    public sst() { }
}

public class SharedString
{
    public string t;        
}
```

I have been unable to edit this class in a way that will correctly interpret both t elements text values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one myself after studying more about xml serialization and many other similar questions to this one on here.

sst class:

```
public class sst
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string uniqueCount;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string count;

    [XmlElement("si")]
    public SharedString[] si;



    public sst() { }
}

public class SharedString
{
    public string t;

    [XmlElement("r")]
    public NestedString[] ns;

    public SharedString() { }

}

public class NestedString
{
    public string t;
}
```

And the assignment of cell's text:

```
if (Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].t != null)
{
   Text = Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].t;
}
else if (Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].ns != null)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].ns.Length; i++)
   {
     Text += Workbook.SharedStrings.si[Convert.ToInt32(_value)].ns[i].t;
   }
}
```